# How to refresh a single component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an Article container. I pass the single article in map function throw props. Like

```
articles.map(d => 
       <Article article={d} />
)
```

In the Article component there are upvote, delete, downvote operations. Now I want when a operations is succeed then the Article component should refresh.

Now I have a working solution:

```
useEffect(() => {
if(deleteSuccess || voteSuccess){
dispatch(getAllArticles()) // I don't want this way, because this will fetch all the articles again, so the 
                            Article component also refreshing, but I want to refresh only the current article in 
                           Article component
}
}, [dispatch, deleteSuccess, voteSuccess])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the component state to force refreshing it. I don't see your code but I guess you have something like this:

```
class Article extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {...};
  }

  render() {
     return ...
  }
}
```

The values that must refresh the view when changing should be inside the state object. So when you make a change, you use setState:

```
setState({upvoted: true});
```

And the view will refresh without re-loading all the Articles. That works for Upvote and Downvote, as for any other change. But not for remove.

When removing, you should update the list, but that doesn't mean fetching the Articles again from your API. You can keep the same Articles you've got, just remove the item from the list and **update the list component state** to refresh that view.

Comment: By using state changes I can update only DOM (e.g button disabled), but its not changing that article realtime value, I mean when I upvote it increase 1, so for show upvote update we have to call api again. 
I think GraphQL can resolve this.